# SendEmail in ASP.net shows me Syntax error, command unrecognized. The server response was: Dovecot ready

Tags: asp.net

I want to send mail using ASP.NET with this code:

```
 public void Semail(string subject, string messageBody, string toAddress)
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.To.Add(toAddress);
        //mail.To.Add("amit_jain_online@yahoo.com");
        mail.From = new MailAddress("noreplykaramaoozi@eesharif.edu");
        mail.Subject = subject;
        string Body = messageBody;
        mail.Body = Body;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "sina.sharif.ir"; //Or Your SMTP Server Address

        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential
            ("noreplykaramaoozi@eesharif.edu", "******");
        //Or your Smtp Email ID and Password
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.Send(mail);
    }
```

But after executing i got this error :

```
 Syntax error, command unrecognized. The server response was: Dovecot ready.
```

This is the stacktrace

```
[SmtpException: Syntax error, command unrecognized. The server response was: Dovecot ready.]
   System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint) +2176152
   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) +2188821
   Novitiate.fa.Register.btnLogin_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +2948
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +154
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3707
```

Comment: Last time when I got this `Dovecot` issue that was due to wrong port number.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There might be issue with SMTP Server.

Try with GMAIL Settings, if mail is working with GMAIL server, then most probably there is issue with your Mailing Server.
It looks like you are using POP3 or IMAP server not SMTP Server, please check configuration of your Server

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
            {
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myusername@gmail.com", "mypwd"),
                EnableSsl = true
            };
            client.Send("myusername@gmail.com", "myusername@gmail.com", "test", "testbody");
            Console.WriteLine("Sent");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: Worked great, thanks! Had trouble finding this info.

Answer (score 8):

When using gmail smtp server and ssl be sure to use 587 port instead of 465, this solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error. It turned out that my router was blocking the port.

To find what was wrong I first (on windows) installed telnet by
typing windows in the bottom search ->
then clicking turn windows features on or off ->
in the windows features list click the telnet checkbox then click ok.
You can now open a command prompt and run this telnet command. The first time i run them the command prompt just hung on both until i rung my ISP to find how to open the port. Now when i ran the below commands...

telnet mail.mydomain.co.uk 465
command prompt just hung so this was blocked on the mail server

telnet mail.mydomain.co.uk 587
give an immediate response telling me that this port was open